# How to check that element length has changed before continuing function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pause a function to check the state of an element and only continue when the state has changed?

Here's my function :

**JS**

```
 download : function() { 

    var loading         = $('#stats-table > div > div.jtable-busy-message').html();

        while (loading.length > 0) {
            alert("Table still loading, please wait to download report"); 
            loading = $('#stats-table > div > div.jtable-busy-message').html(); 
        }

        // continue with the rest of the function here

    }
```

What should I replace the illustrative `while` loop with in the above function in order to pause the function and check the `.length` of `loading` for a change before proceeding with the function.

For information, the `loading` variable either has a length of `18` and `0` - so simply checking for this change in length.

So until the length changes do not continue with the rest of the method body.

**UPDATE**

I've found a simple way of doing this, so no longer require any answers - thanks

Comment: You need to parse the value before making the comparisson

Comment: You could look at "waitForKeyElements": https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891 it does what you're trying to do I think.

Answer (score 0):

No, Javascript is (mostly) single threaded and its impossible for the state to change unless some other piece of code changed it.  Any such change cannot happen "mid function".   Your `while` loop will just cause the browser to lock up, permanently.

If you're waiting for an asynchronous load operation to complete, then your code needs to continue from within that operation's completion callback.

Comment: well, indeed, although that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.fn.exists = function(callback) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

  if (this.length) {
    callback.call(this, args);
  }

  return this;
};

// Usage
$('div.test').exists(function() {
  //do your stuff 
});
​
```

This might helps you :)

Comment: Sorry, not following this at all. Could you make it less general and more related to my variable names and structure above? Thanks

Comment: use this : `var loading = $document.find('#stats-table > div > div.jtable-busy-message').html()` or Could you please make a jsfiddle of your current code?

Comment: It's not the variable I'm unsure about... Where does `loading` get passed into the above solution?